# What is the proper way to select an item randomly from an array when writing factories with factory_girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

If I have types defined in a module inside a model, and an array of these types also defined in the same model, how can I call a value from this array randomly when defining a new factory?

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482149/ruby-pick-randomly-from-an-array) - use `Array#sample`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Foo Bar"
    foo { [:a, :list, :of, :values].sample }
  end
end
```

Comment: Easy to use for integers:
`
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    bar { (1..99).to_a.sample(3) }
  end
end
`