# Picking random element from array

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pick randomly from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482149/how-do-i-pick-randomly-from-an-array)

What is the appropriate way to ensure that a non-existent item isn't chosen?

```
 icons = %w[asterisk star arrow]
 random = rand(icons.length)
```

or

```
icons = %w[asterisk star arrow]
random = rand(icons.length -1)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about using [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample)

```
[1, 2, 3].sample(1)
```

> sample → obj
>   sample(random: rng) → obj
>   sample(n) → new_ary
>   sample(n, random: rng) → new_ary
>   Choose a random element or n random elements from the array. The elements are chosen by using random and unique indices into the array in order to ensure that an element doesn’t repeat itself unless the array already contained duplicate elements. If the array is empty the first form returns nil and the second form returns an empty array.
>   If rng is given, it will be used as the random number generator.

(Assuming you are more interested on the element rather than the index)

Comment: I wasn't even aware of this ... but yes, much more interested in the element. Thanks!

Comment: @JustinM You should accept *this* answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

It would be the first one.

```
icons = %w[asterisk star arrow]
random = rand(icons.length)
```

As stated in the documentation:

> When the argument is an Integer or a Bignum, it returns a random integer greater than or equal to zero and **less than the argument**.

So, if the array is composed of 10 elements (0 .. 9), a rand(10) should return a number between 0 and 9.

Source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Random.html

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as it directly answers the question, though I wasn't aware of sample, which seems nice and tidy. I'll upvote the others.

Comment: Reimplementation of a built-in method is not the correct answer to any question :)

Comment: Nevertheless, is correct and took effort, at least +1

Comment: @Mark Thomas, there are various reasons why reimplementation can be a correct answer. Not saying my answer follows any of that reasons, but I have to disagree with you on that one. Also, despite not answering directly the question, I agree that clyfe's answer is more correct given the purpose of the question, and should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

```
icons = %w[asterisk star arrow]
puts icons.sample
```