# Getting random element from ruby array (your solution)?

Tags: ruby, arrays, random

what is your version to this problem ?
i'm doing so:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
puts array.sort_by { array }.first    
puts array[rand(array.size)]
puts array.shuffle.first
puts array.sample
```

Comment: may be the answer of this question valuable for your: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482149/how-do-i-pick-randomly-from-an-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `array.sample`.  It is MUCH easier to read than the first 2 and slightly easier to read than the third.