# Select random unique element from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482149/how-do-i-pick-randomly-from-an-array) goes over how to select random elements from an array using [sample](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/sample), but I'd like to do this multiple times, selecting a unique one each time.

The simplest solution I can think of is something like this, but I feel like there must be a simpler way (without modifying the original array):

```
myArray = ["stuff", "widget", "ruby", "goodies", "java", "emerald", "etc" ]

selected = []

first = myArray.sample
selected << first

second = myArray.sample
while(selected.include? second) do
  second = myArray.sample
end

selected << second
```

EDIT:

In my specific case, I am not immediately calling one after the other, so using an argument with sample won't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
(myArray - selected).sample
```

E.g. if:

```
selected = ['ruby', 'goodies']
```

then:

```
myArray - selected #=> ["stuff", "widget", "java", "emerald", "etc"]
```

So, the `sample` will be taken out of `["stuff", "widget", "java", "emerald", "etc"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass additional argument number to `sample(n)` and it will return a new array for you

```
myArray = ["stuff", "widget", "ruby", "goodies", "java", "emerald", "etc" ]
n = myArray.length

# The elements are chosen by using random and unique indices and doesn’t repeat itself 
selected = myArray.sample(n)
```

Second option is to use `slice!` and `rand` with seed:

```
myArray = ["stuff", "widget", "ruby", "goodies", "java", "emerald", "etc" ]
myArray_copy = myArray
selected = []

selected << myArray_copy.slice!(rand(myArray_copy.length - 1))
```

Comment: i dont call it all at once though, so this won't help me (but is a valid answer for the stated question)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the method `uniq`. Assuming your `array` is `ary`, call:

```
 ary.uniq{|x| x.user_id}
```

and this will return a set with unique `user_ids`.

Comment: what exactly do you mean a set of user_ids? like the entire set in a random order?