# (Ruby)Select an element in the array randomly

Tags: arrays, ruby

Select a element in the array randomly WITHOUT using the `Random` class.

```
id={1,2,3,4,5}
```

Is there any method which belongs to the `Array` class that is used to randomly select an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sample method

```
[:foo, :bar].sample # => :foo, or :bar :-)
```

Credit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482149/how-do-i-pick-randomly-from-an-array) SO question/answer