# How to select a href link randomly | Watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

Using the following HTML I am trying to randomly select one of the href links

```
<div class="field">
<a href="/destinations/caribbean/british-virgin-islands/tortola-power-charter/availability">Check availability</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last">
<article id="node-cruise-47" class="node node-cruise node-search-result node-cruise-search-result node-published node-not-promoted node-not-sticky author-admin odd clearfix s-search-result" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<div class="search-result-inner clearfix">
<div class="s-search-result--left">
<div class="s-search-result--middle">
<div class="s-search-result--right">
<div class="field field-name-field-price field-type-number-decimal field-label-inline clearfix price-summary">
<div class="field field-name-field-departure-duration field-type-number-integer field-label-hidden price-conditions primary-condition">Based on 7 nights, yacht only</div>
<div class="availability-button-wrapper-search">
<div class="field">
<a href="/destinations/caribbean/british-virgin-islands/tortola-crewed-charter/availability">Check availability</a>
```

Note that several href links are present on the page not just these 2. I am using the following code

```
b.links(:xpath => '//div[@class="field"]/a').click
```

However I get:

```
"undefined method `click' for #<Watir::AnchorCollection:0x2ba1858> (NoMethodError)"
```

Comment: You mean you're trying to randomly click a link on a page programatically?  Does it have to be done using Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to [pick randomly from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482149/how-do-i-pick-randomly-from-an-array)

```
b.links(:xpath => '//div[@class="field"]/a').to_a.sample.click
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how to_a.sample works? Still fairly new to this

Comment: [Sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample)  is stadard method of Array, [to_a](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/ElementCollection#to_a-instance_method) allows to use collection as array

Comment: @Artem maybe nit-picky but to_a changes the collection into an array and returns it. It does not use the collection as an array.  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a The above may not be ideal either since a big page with a lot of links may result in double the work of collecting all the links, translating it to an array & then using sample. You may as well count the size of the collection & use a random number gen to select one of item in the collection.

If the op is looking for a generalized sanity test check out https://github.com/marmelab/gremlins.js