# How can I get random images from specific folder in google drive?

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I'm developing using Ruby Sinatra and currently using:

```
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'google-api-client' , '~> 0.9'


@service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
@service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
@service.authorization = authorize

get_images = @service.list_files(q: "'xxxx' in parents and trashed = false",
  order_by: 'createdTime desc',
  spaces: 'drive',
  fields:'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  page_size: 10)

get_images.files.each do |file|
 ......
end
```

I want to display the images randomly, but

How can I get random image in a folder which contains many images ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pick randomly from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482149/how-do-i-pick-randomly-from-an-array)

Comment: Simply use 'sample': get_images.files.sample, which will return a random file each time.

Comment: Hi, using 'sample' will select 1 data from array. What if I need 10 random data/images from array?

Comment: I think I got it. 'shuffle' do the trick get_images.files.shuffle.each do |file| ...end

Thanks @DaImTo