# Sample with replacement in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Following this simple but very convenient method to [sample from an array without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483802/5783745), we can see something like

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
arr.sample(10)
=> ["b", "a", "d", "f", "e", "c"]
```

How is same accomplished, but ***with replacement***? So in the example `.sample(10)` would return an array of length 10 with some duplicate elements?

e.g.

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
arr.sample(10)
=> ["b", "a", "d", "f", "e", "c", "b", "e", "a", "b"]
```

Comment: Another way: `10.times.map { arr[rand arr.size]  } #=> => ["c", "a", "d", "e", "a", "f", "a", "b", "f", "d"] `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take 1 sample 10 times and collect the result:

```
 10.times.map{arr.sample}
```