# Get n random records where n is stored in a table

Tags: sql, random, sample, teradata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to randomly select rows in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql)

Suppose that -- in Teradata 12 -- I have a table TXN that has Transaction_ID and Store_nbr.
Suppose also that I have a table SAMP that has Store_nbr and n_samples.

Suppose I want to take a sample of n_samples Transaction_IDs from TXN.  I.e., I want the SAMP table to be able to drive how many transaction_id samples are taken from the TXN table.  E.g.,

```
TXN
Transaction_ID Store_nbr
1              1
2              1
1              2
2              2
3              2
```

...and...

```
SAMP
store_nbr n_samples
1         2
2         2
3         1
```

So how can I tell SQL (this is Teradata, btw): Give me 2 samples of transaction_Id for store 1, 2 samples of transaction_Id for store 2, and 1 sample of transaction_Id for store 3?

Teradata does have the conditional sample concept:

```
select a,b
from foo
sample when a=1 then 5
       when a=2 then 10
       when a=3 then 7
end
```

...which I could use a codegen method to create if needed (there are thousands of stores).

The SAMP table is free to change at any time.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't know why this was closed, it's not at all similar to the other question.  Perhaps it can be asked again?  Technically the question should be "how can I do stratified random sampling in Teradata".  I do this myself, but using SAS not "pure" Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `row_number` and `random()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by store_nbr
                                order by random(1,100000)) as seqnum
      from txn t
     ) t join
     samp s
     on t.store_nbr = s.store_nbr and
        t.seqnum <= s.n_samples
```

I'm not aware of a simple syntax using `sample` to accomplish this.

Out of curiousity, would this be allowed?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by store_nbr
                                order by rnd) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, random(1,100000) as rnd from txn t) t
     ) t join
     samp s
     on t.store_nbr = s.store_nbr and
        t.seqnum <= s.n_samples
```

Comment: I like the concept, except that random isn't allowed in ordered analytic functions.