# how to choose random database id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that stores usernames, how can I randomly select a username from the database, by their ID.

So choose a random ID from the existing IDs inside of the database and return the username.

Thanks !

Comment: Quick and dirty, checkout `RAND()`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1209946/980615

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to randomly select rows in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql)

Comment: what does the LIMIT 1 mean ?

Comment: It limits the number of rows returned by your SQL query, 1 row (user), in this case.

Comment: Probably `SELECT id` if that is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple `ORDER BY`.

```
select * from table order by rand() limit 1
```