# how to fetch data from database randomly?

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now i am just using simple query to fetch data but it fetching like the way i store in database linewise . But i want to fetch randomly but how ??

here is my query

```
Select * from FOOD where food_price <= ?
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

```
Select * from FOOD where food_price <= ? ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in a range from 1 to 100:

```
SELECT * FROM FOOD WHERE food_price <= ? ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: and if i dont want it in range then ?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server I use newid():

```
select *
from FOOD
where price <= ?
order by newid();
```

Comment: showing error Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object