# how to display the questions in random manner?

Tags: php, mysql

I got this test script which I anyways am converting it to pdo now but I need a bit of help from one of you pros, I need to display the questions in a random manner not in sequence. i need to randomize the qnid but if i add ORDER BY qnid RAND() no records display on the screen

here is the part from SQL query which i assume is fetching the questions

```
if(isset($_SESSION['stdname']))
{
   $result=executeQuery("select stdanswer,answered from studentquestion where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";");
   $r1=mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $result=executeQuery("select * from question where testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";");
   $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

the database structure

```
--
-- Table structure for table `question`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
  `testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `question` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optiona` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionb` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optiond` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correctanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL,
  `marks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`testid`,`qnid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `question`
--
```

here is the entire script incase if someone could figure it out?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include_once 'oesdb.php';
$final=false;
if(!isset($_SESSION['stdname'])) {
    $_GLOBALS['message']="Session Timeout.Click here to <a href=\"index.php\">Re-LogIn</a>";
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
{
    //Log out and redirect login page
       unset($_SESSION['stdname']);
       header('Location: index.php');

}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['dashboard'])){
    //redirect to dashboard
    //
     header('Location: stdwelcome.php');

    }else if(isset($_REQUEST['next']) || isset($_REQUEST['summary']) || isset($_REQUEST['viewsummary']))
    {
        //next question
        $answer='unanswered';
        if(time()<strtotime($_SESSION['endtime']))
        {
            if(isset($_REQUEST['markreview']))
            {
                $answer='review';
            }
            else if(isset($_REQUEST['answer']))
            {
                $answer='answered';
            }
            else
            {
                $answer='unanswered';
            }
            if(strcmp($answer,"unanswered")!=0)
            {
                if(strcmp($answer,"answered")==0)
                {
                    $query="update studentquestion set answered='answered',stdanswer='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['answer'],ENT_QUOTES)."' where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query="update studentquestion set answered='review',stdanswer='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['answer'],ENT_QUOTES)."' where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";";
                }
                if(!executeQuery($query))
                {
                // to do
                $_GLOBALS['message']="Your previous answer is not updated.Please answer once again";
                }
                closedb();
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['viewsummary']))
            {
                 header('Location: summary.php');
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['summary']))
             {
                     //summary page
                     header('Location: summary.php');
             }
        }
        if((int)$_SESSION['qn']<(int)$_SESSION['tqn'])
        {
        $_SESSION['qn']=$_SESSION['qn']+1;

        }
        if((int)$_SESSION['qn']==(int)$_SESSION['tqn'])
        {
           $final=true;
        }

    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['previous']))
    {
    // Perform the changes for current question
        $answer='unanswered';
        if(time()<strtotime($_SESSION['endtime']))
        {
            if(isset($_REQUEST['markreview']))
            {
                $answer='review';
            }
            else if(isset($_REQUEST['answer']))
            {
                $answer='answered';
            }
            else
            {
                $answer='unanswered';
            }
            if(strcmp($answer,"unanswered")!=0)
            {
                if(strcmp($answer,"answered")==0)
                {
                    $query="update studentquestion set answered='answered',stdanswer='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['answer'],ENT_QUOTES)."' where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query="update studentquestion set answered='review',stdanswer='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['answer'],ENT_QUOTES)."' where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";";
                }
                if(!executeQuery($query))
                {
                // to do
                $_GLOBALS['message']="Your previous answer is not updated.Please answer once again";
                }
                closedb();
            }
        }
        //previous question
        if((int)$_SESSION['qn']>1)
        {
            $_SESSION['qn']=$_SESSION['qn']-1;
        }

    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['fs']))
    {
        //Final Submission
        header('Location: testack.php');
    }
?>
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <!-- Meta Tag -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Conducter</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE"/>
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE"/>
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NONE"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oes.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cdtimer.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    <!--
        <?php
                $elapsed=time()-strtotime($_SESSION['starttime']);
                if(((int)$elapsed/60)<(int)$_SESSION['duration'])
                {
                    $result=executeQuery("select TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(endtime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'%H') as hour,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(endtime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'%i') as min,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(endtime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'%s') as sec from studenttest where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid'].";");
                    if($rslt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                     echo "var hour=".$rslt['hour'].";";
                     echo "var min=".$rslt['min'].";";
                     echo "var sec=".$rslt['sec'].";";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_GLOBALS['message']="Try Again";
                    }
                    closedb();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "var sec=01;var min=00;var hour=00;";
                }
        ?>

    -->
    </script>

    </head>
  <body >
      <noscript><h2>For the proper Functionality, You must use Javascript enabled Browser</h2></noscript>
       <?php

        if($_GLOBALS['message']) {
            echo "<div class=\"message\">".$_GLOBALS['message']."</div>";
        }
        ?>
      <div id="container"><div class="header">
                <img style="margin:10px 2px 2px 10px;float:left;" src="images/logo.gif" alt="OES"/><h3 class="headtext"> </h3>
            </div>
           <form id="testconducter" action="testconducter.php" method="post">
          <div class="menubar" style="text-align:center;">
              <h2 style="font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight:bolder;font-size:120%;color:#fff;padding-top:0.3em;letter-spacing:1px;">Test Conducter</h2>
          </div>
      <div class="page">
          <?php

          if(isset($_SESSION['stdname']))
          {
                $result=executeQuery("select stdanswer,answered from studentquestion where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";");
                $r1=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $result=executeQuery("select * from question where testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";");
                $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
          ?>
          <div class="tc">

              <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                  <tr>
                      <th style="width:50%;"><h3><span id="timer" class="timerclass"></span></h3></th>
                      <th style="width:40%;"><h4 style="color: #af0a36;">Q No: <?php echo $_SESSION['qn']; ?> </h4></th>
                      <th style="width:40%;"><h4 style="color: #af0a36;"><input type="checkbox" name="markreview" value="mark"> Review</input></h4></th>
                  </tr>
              </table>
             <textarea cols="100" rows="8" name="question" readonly style="width:96.8%;text-align:left;margin-left:2%;margin-top:2px;font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:0;color:#0000ff;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['question'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></textarea>
              <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                  <tr><td >1. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optiona" <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"review")==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"answered")==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),"optiona")==0 ){echo "checked";} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optiona'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>
                  <tr><td >2. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optionb" <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"review")==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"answered")==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),"optionb")==0 ){echo "checked";} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optionb'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>
                  <tr><td >3. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optionc" <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"review")==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"answered")==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),"optionc")==0 ){echo "checked";} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optionc'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>
                  <tr><td >4. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optiond" <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"review")==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"answered")==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),"optiond")==0 ){echo "checked";} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optiond'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th style="width:80%;"><h4><input type="submit" name="<?php if($final==true){ echo "viewsummary" ;}else{ echo "next";} ?>" value="<?php if($final==true){ echo "View Summary" ;}else{ echo "Next";} ?>" class="subbtn"/></h4></th>
                      <th style="width:12%;text-align:right;"><h4><input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous" class="subbtn"/></h4></th>
                      <th style="width:8%;text-align:right;"><h4><input type="submit" name="summary" value="Summary" class="subbtn" /></h4></th>
                  </tr>

              </table>


          </div>
          <?php
          closedb();
          }
          ?>
      </div>

           </form>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `ORDER BY RAND()` and not `ORDER BY qnid RAND()`

Comment: Select a random row with MySQL:
`SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: did that too but nothing gets randomized. could it be like even the sequence is stored in session in the script above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomly select rows in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql)

Comment: Your query looks for `testid` and `qnid`, if this numbers are unique for a question, why should the sql return different questions?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile no it isn't because i am unable to figure out where in the script above i actually need to edit and where i am doing nothing is happening.

Comment: testid is unique but qnid is not and i need to randomly display the questions on the screen not serially like 1 2 3 4 5 insteal i want it like 5 2 3 4 1 types

Comment: So here's the problem, you're selecting one question at a time. Getting questions in a random order means you might select the same question next time as well (which I'm guessing is not what you want). You need to pre-select all questions within a test in a random order (e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE testid=... ORDER BY rand()` ) and then display them in the order you got them that one time.