# Lucky Draw Concept : SQL Query to get random option based on percentage of appearance

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am developing a Lucky draw concept as following

There will be multiple options at database we have to get the random options according to percentage of appearance

Database table is as following

```
option_id |   option_name |  option_type | option_in_day(%) |  option_status
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1             $2 Off         2             100                 1
2             $3 Off         2             95                  1
3             $4 Off         2             95                  1
4             $5 Off         2             90                  1
5             $8 Off         2             90                  1
6             $60 Cashback   2             10                  1
7             $100 Cashback  2             5                   1
8             Umbrela        2             50                  1
9             Iphone         2             2                   1
10            International
              Tour           2             1                   1
11            Fidget 
              Spinner        2             70                  1
12            Free 
              membership     2             30                  1
13            Samsung S8     2             10                  1
14            $20 Off        2             60                  1
15            Travel Card    2             50                  1
16            Soft Toys      2             70                  1
```

Now from this table I want to get random 8 option according to percentage.

Less percentage option chance to retrieve in result will be less.

I have tried with random function in sql but can't reach the requirement.

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql). Did you try this? `SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 8`

Comment: i have already tried @Regolith  but i have to do it based on percentage given in data

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should be able to do it:

```
set @percentage = 100 * rand();
select *
from table_name
order by table_name.percentage >= @percentage, rand()
limit 0, 8;
```

This query stores a random percentage into a variable. Then, we order the query by two criterias. The first criteria is that the `percentage` of the `table` is higher or equal to the `percentage` randomized. This makes sure that if there are elements both above and below the randomized `percentage`, then the elements above will be preferred. Elements having similar result in the first ordering criteria will be randomly ordered.