# Select a percentage of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have a table where is over 50 000 rows, from that table I want to select random percentages of rows.

Below are member types that are stored in one column(Member Type) and I need to select random percentage of each of the 7 member type. Also the percentages are not from the total number of rows but only random 8000 from that table.

- Private Associate - 40% from random 8000 rows
- Associate Member Under 35 - 21% from random 8000 rows
- Private Full Member - 13% from random 8000 rows
- Public Associate - 12% from random 8000 rows
- Associate Student - 8% from random 8000 rows
- Public Full Member - 3% from random 8000 rows
- Full Member U35 - 1% from random 8000 rows

What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: Rows in *what*? A spreadsheet? A database? A dataframe in R or pandas? What *language* are you using? In any event, what is the problem? 40% of 8000 is 3200 -- just randomly select 3200 rows from the Private Associate rows. Similarly for the other categories. Just how you would do that depends heavily on your answers to the above questions.

Comment: My apologies, in database using SQl Management Studio 2014. I have never constructed similar query, right it makes sense. I know math. In my query I am joining 7 tables. One of them is the one where Member Type is store, my question would be where in the query do I specify the number of rows for each category ?

Comment: LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON cst_key=mem_cst_key                                                                                       this is a join for the table where I would like to select the specified number of rows. Would I specify it here? Thanks John

Comment: Stick an ORDER BY NEWID() on the query

Comment: See this link to randomize your data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209946/100283 anthem take a look at the link to top percentage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql