# Update each row with a random selected value from list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `Users` with an integer column named `status` and i want to select a random value from integer list `(10,20, 30)`  and set to `status` for each row.

I'm using this:

```
update "Users" set "status" = i.a from (select a  from (SELECT 30 AS a
UNION ALL SELECT 10 AS a
UNION ALL SELECT 20 AS a) as s order by random() limit 1) i
```

Result:

```
id  | status  

 1      20
 2      20
 3      20
 -- other rows have the same status value (20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `from` clause is executed only once -- hence you only get one value.

If you didn't have a list, the simplest way would be:

```
update users
    set status = cast(random() * 3 as int) * 10;
```

You can try this version:

```
update Users
    set status = (select a
                  from (values (30), (10), (20) ) v(a)
                  limit 1
                 );
```

However, I think that Postgres will "optimize" away the subquery and decide to execute it only once.  (I consider this a bug, because `random()` is volatile, but that is another matter.)

If that happens, correlating the subquery to the outer query usually fixes the problem:

```
update Users
    set status = (select a
                  from (values (30), (10), (20) ) v(a)
                  where users.status <> v.a
                  order by random()
                  limit 1
                 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You need some query to select a random value in the `set` clause like:

```
UPDATE Users
SET
Status = (
    SELECT TOP 1 [value]
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM string_split('10,20,30', ',')
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    )
)
```

you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql) to see different ways to use random values in different DBS. (This example work for SQL server)