# How can I select a row within a group based on a condition in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

**Question**
Please consider the following table:

```
+--------------+--------+--------+
| transactionID | Sgroup | Rgroup |
+--------------+--------+--------+
|            1 | A      | I      |
|            1 | A      | J      |
|            2 | B      | B      |
|            2 | B      | K      |
+--------------+--------+--------+
```

For each `transactionID` (2 rows are associated with ID 1, two rows with ID 2) I want to select the row for which `Sgroup = Rgroup`, if any row within a `transactionID` satisfies the condition. Otherwise, I want to select a row at random. For each `transactionID` at most one row satisfies `Sgroup = Rgroup`. How can I do this?

**Attempted Solution**
I know how to select rows for which the condition `Sgroup = Rgroup` is fulfilled as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction 
WHERE Sgroup = Rgroup;

+---------------+--------+--------+
| transactionID | Sgroup | Rgroup |
+---------------+--------+--------+
|             2 | B      | B      |
+---------------+--------+--------+
```

I also know how to chose a row randomly (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql)) if the condition is not fulfilled as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE NOT transactionID IN
(SELECT transactionID
FROM Transaction 
WHERE Sgroup = Rgroup)
ORDER BY RAND()) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.transactionID;

+---------------+--------+--------+
| transactionID | Sgroup | Rgroup |
+---------------+--------+--------+
|             1 | A      | I      |
+---------------+--------+--------+
```

How can I combine these two expressions into one? I tried working with a CASE expression I didn't get far. Can somebody kindly suggest a solution?

**Example Code** Here is the code to generate the table:

```
CREATE DATABASE MinimalExample;
USE MinimalExample;

CREATE TABLE Transaction (
transactionID int,
Sgroup nvarchar(1),
Rgroup nvarchar(1)
);

INSERT INTO Transaction VALUES
(1,'A','I'), 
(1,'A','J'),
(2,'B','B'),
(2,'B','K');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think variables might be the simplest solution if you really mean "random":

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@i = transactionID, @rn + 1,
                        if(@i := transactionID, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by transactionID, (sgroup = rgroup) desc, rand()
           ) t cross join
           (select @i := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```

If by "random" you mean "arbitrary", you can use this quick-and-dirty trick:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where sgroup = rgroup
)
union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.sgroup = t2.rgroup)
 group by transactionID
);
```

This uses the dreaded `select *` with `group by`, something which I strongly discourage using under almost all circumstances.  However, in this case, you are specifically trying to reduce each group to an *indeterminate* row, so it doesn't seem quite so bad.  I will note that MySQL does not guarantee that the columns in the result set all come from the same row, although in practice they do.

Finally, if you had a unique primary key on each row, you could use probably the simplest solution:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.transactionID = t.transactionID
              order by (rgroup = sgroup) desc, rand()
             );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The first (simplest) solution looks very interesting to me and works but I don't fully comprehend it. Can you kindly describe it a little bit?

Comment: @fabian . . . Read the documentation in MySQL on variables.  Then run the subqueries to see what the results are (perhaps just for one or two transctions).