# SQL To retrieve 50 random user with their all transaction records

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I want to pull data to anayze user behaviour transaction. I just need to randomly select 50 user for each dates with their transaction record. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please show the structure of the involved tables

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try like this in sql server

```
SELECT TOP 50 column FROM table ORDER BY NEWID()
```

for more information you can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209946/5184745)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row per user, then you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by random()
limit 50;
```

If you have multiple rows per user and want the complete data for 50 of them, then you can use `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select distinct user_id
      from t
      order by random()
      limit 50
     ) u50
     on t.user_id = u50.user_id;
```